# Set-Cookie is not working inside the fetch in nextauth authentication

Tags: next.js, cookies, next-auth

I want to create a cookie containing my access token but the `new Response() headers Set-Cookie` is not working. When I use the `cookies().set()` inside my `[...nextauth]/route.ts` it is working but I want to serialize it so I do this.

### [...nextauth]/route.ts

`const res = await fetch(domainname+"/api/auth/login",{options})`

### `api/auth/login/route.ts`

```
const serialized = serialize(COOKIE_NAME,accessToken,{
secure:false,
sameSite:'lax',
httpOnly: true,
path: '/',
maxAge:3600
})

return new Response(
  JSON.stringify(res),
  {
   status:200,
   headers:{"Set-Cookie":serialized}
})
```

I tried to set my cookie inside the `login/route.ts` but it is not working. I tried to use `cookies().set()` in my `login/route.ts` and it is not working too.I can set a cookie inside my `[...nextauth]/route.ts` using the `cookies().set()` but my problem is, I want to serialize it but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me please.